# I have to manually open the Nvidia X Server Settings GUI after every boot to not get lag/tearing, how to load it automatically?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, tearing, nvidia-settings

I've recently bought an Nvidia graphics card (was a Radeon user with the FOSS-drivers previously) and I installed the hardware and the proprietary drivers, because I need the GLS Extensions for some programs.

Unfortunately, I notced heavy lag and tearing on Xfce with different compositors (Xfwm, Compton, Compiz), which the `{ ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }` parameter in the xorg.conf settings seems to fix. Unfortunately, I always have to manually start the Nvidia X Server Settings GUI program from the launcher once for this to take effect, else I get heavy tearing and input lag.

I already searched for a solution here and on other websites and found the official Nvidia guide on adding `nvidia-settings -load-config-only` either to the startup applications or to the xinitrc-file. However, none of these work for me (the driver also apparently created a startup item already). Also, my dual screen layout **is** saved upon reboot, it's just another setting that is only called when I open the Nvidia Settings GUI and in the same second, all tearing and lagging effects are gone from the desktop environment until the next restart.

I can solve this problem by solely adding `nvidia-settings` to the startup applications and manually closing it every time, but that's not very elegant and a bit annoying.

Is there anything else that I could try?

Comment: Could maybe try a cronjob after reboot by running `contab -e` -> and add a line like `@reboot <command to perform>`

Comment: You run nvidia-settings as root and save your changes and/or re-write your xorg.conf. We need more details to write an xorg.conf for you.